# How does moment .toDate() find the timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Locally, a call to .toDate returns the correct time for me (GMT+1). But when I vpn to a client system which is (GMT+3), the time that is returned is as if I am in UTC. Could it be possible that it is also correctly showing for the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toDate always works with the browser's/systems timezone. It is not clear if your are using javascript on the server, but I assume you are using nodejs and the webserver uses UTC.

Comment: Thanks! The backend on the server is java and yes it uses UTC. The issue was the machine I was VPN'ing from had a timezone of GMT which meant the browser thought it was in GMT.

Answer (score 0):

mmoment JS now has an [guess() API](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) to detect the current user timezone

```
moment.tz.guess();
moment.tz.zone(moment.tz.guess())
```